Нормально ли использовать ThunkAction только для запросов по сети без изменения состояния приложения?
Нормально ли использовать ThunkAction только для запросов по сети, без изменения состояния приложения? Не хочется совершать запрос в самом компоненте, чтобы потом было в будущем легче написать тесты
